# Converter valor de tempo de duração

Tags: r

Preciso converter os valores de um atributo que está no formato de tempo de duração hh:mm:ss para um valor em que eu possa correlacionar com outro atributo em um boxplot.

Os dados são os seguintes:

```
structure(list(tempoEngajamento = structure(c(13L, 21L, 23L, 
24L, 11L, 19L, 25L, 14L, 29L, 18L, 10L, 20L, 7L, 27L, 12L, 4L, 
3L, 6L, 5L, 17L, 2L, 15L, 30L, 16L, 1L, 22L, 28L, 26L, 9L, 8L
), .Label = c("06:53:42", "07:22:22", "104:45:25", "12:53:32", 
"13:28:46", "15:21:12", "15:32:58", "16:36:56", "17:45:46", "19:47:31", 
"20:03:48", "21:14:59", "21:51:09", "22:42:40", "22:43:54", "24:15:09", 
"24:28:28", "25:45:46", "29:55:38", "32:52:21", "32:53:01", "42:24:07", 
"42:35:04", "44:14:25", "49:11:58", "49:42:53", "62:24:01", "64:04:40", 
"76:06:17", "81:25:04"), class = "factor"), notaFinal = c(23.95, 
25.4, 31.55, 25.4, 27.8, 27.3, 31.85, 20.45, 31.95, 28.55, 20, 
24.95, 14.45, 22.55, 25.65, 10.35, 27.95, 21.45, 18.45, 21.1, 
12.3, 22.65, 30.35, 27.4, 12.85, 21.95, 26.25, 28.55, 24.3, 22.35
)), .Names = c("tempoEngajamento", "notaFinal"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Preciso correlacionar o valor da coluna 1 com o da coluna 2, mas para isso o valor da coluna 1 precisa ser convertido para um valor equivalente.

Comment: Eu achei essa resposta nas minhas pesquisas, mas a função que o Marcus Nunes deu, converte apenas um valor. No meu caso tenho vários valores em um dataframe, e não consigo converter todos os valores da coluna 1 com a função que ele sugeriu.

Comment: consegui resolver através da resposta dada pelo Marcus Nunes, só precisei jogar a função em um for para converter linha a linha de meu dataframe.